# Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS issue with black screen after extended sleep time

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, asus, lts, nvidia-geforce

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I am having issues with the display probably incompatibility between hardware and driver(nvidia). Here is the information for my system:

Motherboard : Asus X670-P WIFI

CPU: AMD RYZEN 9 7950X 16 CORE

GPU: GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate

nvidia driver : 535.54.03
GNOME Version : 42.9

Issue: When the system goes to sleep and I want to revive it, most of the times it will not come back up and I just see a black screen with a blinking cursor on the top left. When I restart it, it goes into what I believe is the safe mode and I get my display back(only on one screen, I have 2 screens). I do sudo reboot again and then it might work fine or it may need couple of reboots to finally start. Here is the report of dmesg which is from when I restarted the system and it went to safe mode(icons were big in size on the display). That time nvidia was definitely not being installed I think:

dmesg

```
        [    0.000000] Linux version 5.19.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-025) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1-generic 5.19.17)
        [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic root=UUID=f6d75970-de45-4483-b079-562aa2365354 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
        [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
        [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
        [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
        [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
        [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
        [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX-512 opmask'
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x040: 'AVX-512 Hi256'
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x080: 'AVX-512 ZMM_Hi256'
        [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Protection Keys User registers'
      [    5.088625] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
    [    5.088630] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
    [    5.151086] audit: type=1400 audit(1689863995.787:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=783 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    5.151088] audit: type=1400 audit(1689863995.787:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=783 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    5.167290] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 235
    [    5.168568] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
    [    5.225035] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  535.54.03  Tue Jun  6 22:17:39 UTC 2023
    [    5.236362] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
    [    5.977028] [drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice
    [    5.977131] [drm:nv_drm_probe_devices [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to register device
    [    5.977276] RIP: 0010:_nv000483kms+0x11/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
    [    5.977497]  nv_drm_master_set+0x25/0x50 [nvidia_drm]
    [    5.988166] Modules linked in: cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_drm(PO) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm btusb snd_hda_intel crct10dif_pclmul btrtl ghash_clmulni_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_seq_midi btbcm snd_intel_sdw_acpi aesni_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event btintel crypto_simd btmtk binfmt_misc snd_hda_core snd_rawmidi cryptd nvidia(PO) snd_hwdep nls_iso8859_1 input_leds joydev rapl asus_nb_wmi bluetooth eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof snd_seq snd_pcm ecdh_generic snd_seq_device ecc ccp drm_kms_helper snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops drm reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap platform_profile crc32_pclmul r8169 nvme ahci i2c_piix4
    [    6.317371] RIP: 0010:_nv000483kms+0x11/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
    [    6.436482] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
    [    6.447413] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 511.

other error:
[    1.092803] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[    5.977200] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
```

After the reboot, when everything came back to normal here is the output for dmesg again with respect to nvidia and few errors:

```
[    1.105551] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[    5.185361] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    5.185365] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    5.237108] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 235
[    5.237820] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    5.286489] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  535.54.03  Tue Jun  6 22:17:39 UTC 2023
[    5.296633] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    6.599673] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    6.716157] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    6.733979] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 511.
[   32.320547] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.320588] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.320603] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.320615] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.344463] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.344491] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.344506] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.344517] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.367728] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.367753] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.367766] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   32.367777] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  137.825514] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  137.825554] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

ANy help or fix would be appreciated on this.

Comment: I have a Z790 with Intel I5-12600K internal display. Does the same thing including the multiple reboots to get it to start. MB status lights indicate display not starting. Your post makes me wonder if it's some sort of BIOS issue. Since I use this as a server I just set sleep to never.

Comment: I did sleep to never, and it was fine for overnight, but just now the screen froze and I had to reboot. Not sure what is wrong here. May be I should boot windows with a live usb ?

Comment: Haven't had any lockup issues with sleep on. Been running for weeks now. File sharing to windows breaks and needs a reboot but I don't use it often. Both these motherboards and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS seem very new. Very little of the web info works. I know one of the Ubuntu updates fixed the problem I had with wifi. If it continues to be a problem checking BIOS and Ubuntu updates might help.